# xsplash in Gentoo

Tags: gentoo

I'm trying to install xsplash in Gentoo. I've googled and googled and come up with nothing. I downloaded the sources from https://launchpad.net/xsplash, compiled and installed them without issue, but now what? I can't seem to associate it with any runlevel ("`rc-update -v show`" does not list it).

Any tips? Thanks!
Mala

Comment: Are your set on xsplash for any particular reason, Gentoo has fbsplash in Portage. media-gfx/splashutils

Comment: I've been reading up on the reasons behind using xplash - it actually leads to a significantly faster boot. That and it's really, really pretty ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wavilen.blogspot.com/2009/12/xsplash-sabayon-gentoo.html

translate.google.com to help you